# If $(a,b) =R$ then for all positive integers $n,m$, $(a^n, b,^m) =R$

Tags: ring-theory

Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring with identity, and $a, b \in R$ such that the ideal generated by $a,b$ is equal to the ring, I.e. $(a,b)=R$. Prove that $(a^n, b^m) = R$ for all positive integers $m,n$. I don't really have a clue how to tackle this problem, how do I do it?

Comment: First, try to show that $(a^2,b^2) = R$.

Comment: It may also be useful to you that $(a) \cap (b) = (ab)$ in this case.

Comment: Yes I looked for it, but couldn't find a duplicate. I would appreciate it if you could link it

Comment: @MarcelS I would have, if I could find it. But now I'm thinking that even what I remember was a slight variation of this.

Comment: @rschwieb, the question is exercise 3.4 in Garlings Galois Theory, so I didn't look for counterexamples. In your example (x,x+1)= R clearly, and (x^2,x+1) =(x+1) = R as 1 = (1-x)(1+x) is in (x+1)

Comment: @MarcelS Oh, so it is :) The reason I was suspicious is because i think the variant I saw used $(a^n, b^n)$ rather than letting the powers be independent.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $u a + v b = 1 \implies (u a+ v b) ^{n+m-1} = 1$,  expand.

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** We show by induction that for all $n$, $(a,b^n)=R$. It is clearly true for $n=1$. Now suppose it is true for all positive integers up to $n$: We have $R = (a,b^n)= (a) +(b^n) = (a) + (b^n)((a)+(b))$ $ = (a) + (ab^n) + (b^{n+1}) = (a) + (b^{n+1})$ $ = (a, b^{n+1})$, as $(ab^n) \subseteq (a)$, and hence by induction on $n$ we obtain the result.

**(2)**  We now show for fixed $n$, that for all $m$, $R=(a^m,b^n)$. It is clearly true for $m=1$ (by part **(1)**). Now suppose it is true for all positive integers up to $m$: We have $R =(a^m, b^n) = (a^m)((a) + (b^n)) + (b^n)$ $ = (a^{m+1}) + (a^m b^n) + (b^n)$ $ = (a^{m+1}) + (b^n) = (a^{m+1}, b^n)$, as $(a^m b^n) \subseteq (b^n)$. We obtain our result by induction on $m$ and hence the final result.

Comment: The second step isn't really necessary: Set $b' = b^n$ and use (1).